# Visual Studio - Web Project - add existing area folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vs-web-site-project

We have a big Web Project with Many areas. One area is not included into the project, but its folder exists on the disk (and I also added it to Source Control).

I cannot figure out how to add that Area into the project. There seems to be no option for this. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above the solution tree is a button to show all files in the folder.
When you click it, your folder will appear in the solution.
On this folder click right "Add to solution".

Now your folder is part of the solution and you can hide the unnecessary items.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the ticket! For now turned out I don't need this area and folder, but this is very useful tip for the future.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to manually edit the csproj file. In windows explorer navigate to your directory and right click to edit the csproj (something like notepad++ works really well). Then locate the ItemGroup section that contains all the  elements. Add a new one with your Folder\controller.cs. Save the changes. You'll need to reload the project in VS (if you have it open) to see the changes.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!--Other compile includes-->     
    <Compile Include="MissingArea\XController.cs"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I was thinking about it. I discussed it this morning with my colleagues and turned out I didn't need this particular area at all, so not an issue for now anymore